# Подписка на событие в библиотеки C++ из проекта C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll

Добрый вечер. Подскажите, как написать на C++ библиотеку и потом подключить её в проекте на C# и подвязаться на событие, возникающее в ней?
Простой пример:
есть функция ,которая каждые 10 секунд генерирует на выход значение "Привет".
Программа C# должна реагировать и как только в библиотеке сгенерируется событие - вывести его значение, например alert-ом.
Как такое сделать?
Спасибо

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте [это](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/davidnotario/gotchas-with-reverse-pinvoke-unmanaged-to-managed-code-callbacks).

Из C# передавайте делегат в C++.

В С++ части, скажем, будет такое:

```
typedef void (__stdcall *PFN_MYCALLBACK)(); int __stdcall MyUnmanagedApi(PFN_ MYCALLBACK callback);
```

Тогда в C# коде:

```
public delegate void MyCallback();
[DllImport("MYDLL.DLL")] public static extern void MyUnmanagedApi(MyCallback callback);

public static void Main(){
  MyUnmanagedApi(
    delegate(){
      Console.WriteLine("Called back by unmanaged side");
    }
   );
}
```